# How does voting between two classifiers work in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, ensemble-learning

For a classification task, I am using voting classifier to ensemble logistic regression and SVM with voting parameter set to `soft`. The result is clearly better than each individual model. I am not sure if I understand how it works though. How can the model find the majority vote between only two models?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have two classes `class-A` and `class-B`

`Logistic Regression`( has an inbuilt **predict_proba()** method) and `SVC`(set probability=True) both are able to estimate class probabilities on their outputs i.e. they predict if input is **class-A** with probability **a** and **class-B** with probability **b**. If **a>b** then it outputs predicted class is **A** otherwise **B** .In a voting classifier setting the voting parameter to `soft` enables them(SVM and LogiReg) to calculate their probability(also known as confidence score) individually and present it to the voting classifier, then the `voting classifier` averages them and outputs the class with the highest probability.

Make sure that if you set `voting=soft` then the classifiers you provide can also calculate this confidence score.

To see the confidence of each classifier you can do:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred=classifer_name.predict(X_test) #classifier_name=trained SVM/LogiReg/VotingClassifier
print(classifier_name.__class__.__name__,accuracy_score(y_true,y_pred))
```

**NOTE**:  **a**+**b** may not appear to be **1** due to computer floating point round off. But it is **1**. I can't say about other confidence scores like decision functions, but with predict_proba() it is the case.

Comment: I can't say about other confidence scores like decision functions, but with predict_proba() the sum of all probabilities of a sample equals 1. It may not appear to be 1 due to computer floating point round off. But it is 1.

Comment: @VivekKumar thank you for the clarification, it may be the case. I will update my answer and add your `floating point` round off part.